# Prove that $I^2/\partial I^2$ is homeomorphic to $\mathbb{S}^2$

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, continuity

> Prove that $I^2/ \partial I^2$ is homeomorphic to $\mathbb{S}^2$

This was the idea I came up with to prove the above. I was thinking that I could prove the above by showing that $I^2/ \partial I^2$ was homeomorphic to the one-point compactification of $(0, 1) \times (0, 1)$ which itself is homeomorphic to the one-point compactification of $\mathbb{R}^2$ which is homeomorphic to $\mathbb{S}^2$.

So if I could prove that  $I^2/ \partial I^2$ was homeomorphic to $\left((0, 1)^2\right)^* = (0, 1) \times (0, 1) \cup \{p\}$ which is the one-point compactification of $(0, 1) \times (0, 1)$, then I'd have proven the result.

My strategy to prove $I^2/ \partial I^2 \cong \left((0, 1)^2\right)^*$ was to

1. Define a bijective map $f : I^2/ \partial I^2 \to \left((0, 1)^2\right)^*$
2. Prove $f$ is continuous
3. Since $ I^2/ \partial I^2$ is compact (since it is the quotient of a compact Hausdorff space) and $\left((0, 1)^2\right)^*$ is Hausdorff by the closed map lemma I can conclude that $f$ is a homeomorphism

To that end I defined a map $f : I^2/ \partial I^2 \to \left((0, 1)^2\right)^*$ by $$f\left(\left[(x, y)\right]\right) = \begin{cases}
(x, y) \ \text{ if } (x, y) \in I^2 \setminus \partial I^2\\
p \ \ \ \ \ \  \ \ \text{ if } (x, y) \in  \partial I^2\\
\end{cases}$$

where $p$ is the point added to $(0,1) \times (0, 1)$ in the one point compactification. It's easy to see that $f$ is bijective, since the equivalence classes of points inside $I^2 \setminus \partial I^2 = (0, 1) \times (0, 1)$, which are just singletons are mapped to 'themselves' again, and the equivalence class of points inside the boundary $\partial I^2$  (which is just a single point in the quotient space) is mapped to a single point in the target space.

Now the only part I'm having a bit of difficulty is in showing that $f$ is continuous. The reason for this is because I'm having a bit of trouble finding a workable 'description' of the open sets in the topology of the one point compactification $\left((0, 1)^2\right)^*$. The topology on $\left((0, 1)^2\right)^*$ is given explicitly by $$\mathcal{T} = \{\text{ open subsets of } (0, 1) \times (0, 1) \} \cup \left\{U \subseteq \left((0, 1)^2\right)^* \ | \ \left((0, 1)^2\right)^*\setminus U \text{ is a compact subset of } (0, 1) \times (0, 1) \right\}$$

and I then (using the Heine-Borel theorem) simplified it to

$$\mathcal{T} = \{\text{ open subsets of } (0, 1) \times (0, 1) \} \cup \left\{U \subseteq \left((0, 1)^2\right)^* \ | \ \left((0, 1)^2\right)^*\setminus U \cup \{p\} \text{ is closed in  } \mathbb{R}^2 \right\}$$

So now if I pick an open $U$ in $\left((0, 1)^2\right)^*$, then either $U$ is open in $(0, 1) \times (0, 1)$ or $\left((0, 1)^2\right)^*\setminus U \cup \{p\} \text{ is closed in  } \mathbb{R}^2 $. So I have two cases to prove to show that $f$ is continuous.

In the first case when $U$ is open in $(0, 1) \times (0, 1)$ then by the quotient topology on $I^2 / \partial I^2$ it follows that $f^{-1}[U]$ is open in  $I^2 / \partial I^2$ if and only if $q^{-1}[f^{-1}[U]]$ is open in $I^2$ and $q^{-1}[f^{-1}[U]] = (f \circ q)^{-1}[U] = U$ which is open in $I^2$, so $f^{-1}[U]$ is open in $I^2 / \partial I^2$ and we are done.

In the second case when $\left((0, 1)^2\right)^*\setminus U \cup \{p\} \text{ is closed in  } \mathbb{R}^2 $, I'm not sure how to show $f^{-1}[U]$ is open in this case.

So I have two questions. Firstly is my approach to the initial problem correct? If so my question then is: **How can I show that $f$ is continuous?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One can define a map $I^n \to  S^n$ by requiring that the interior maps to $S^n \setminus \{pt\}$. You can make this formal by taking the inverse of the stereographic projection $s:S^n \setminus \{pt\} \to \mathbb R^n$ and using your favorite homeomorphism $f:\mathrm{Int}(I^n) \to \mathbb R^n$. I recommend an $\tan$ in each co-ordinate. Composing $s^{-1} \circ f$ gives the desired map.
The key now is to see that this map can be extended to the boundary in a continuous fashion. We can be crude about this by defining $\partial D^n \to pt$ and defining the total map piecewise.

To check continuity, take any neighborhood of $\{pt\}$ and note that the preimage is just an open ring in $D^n$. Doing this explicitly might be a good exercise, but I don't think its so interesting.

Anyhow, since this makes the appropriate identifications, we know by the universal property of the quotient topology/map that this total map factors through the quotient, and the induced map is bijective. Since the domain is compact and the codomain hausdorff, it is a homeomorphism.

Answer (score 0):

Actually there is a simpler way to prove this.

> **Theorem 1**: If $A \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$ is a compact convex subset with nonempty interior, then $A \cong D^n$ and moreover $\partial A \cong \partial D$.
>
> **Theorem 2:** $D^n /\partial D^n \cong S^n$

*Proof:* So using this theorem, since $I^n$ is compact (being a finite product of compact sets) and convex we obtain $I^n \cong D^n$ and $\partial I^n \cong \partial D^n$. Now since $D^n /\partial D^n \cong S^n$ it follows that $I^n / \partial I^n \cong S^n$. $\square$

Comment: I guess you would need that a homeomorphism restricts to a homeomorphism $\partial I^n \to \partial D^n$ which is admittedly not that hard

Comment: @AndresMejia In fact that is part of the theorem, let me edit my answer accordingly

Comment: yes, but given the level of the question it might be worth remarking on how one proves such a theorem (radial projection from any closed ball on the interior of a convex set, for example, would do the trick I think.) Theorem 2 is basically the content if your question. If you can prove that, then you can prove your theorem.

Comment: @AndresMejia I'm aware of the proof of the theorem (and yes radial projection does the trick if I remember correctly) and Theorem 2 has a relatively simple proof that I've seen in *Introduction to Topological Manifolds by John Lee*

Comment: okay! As long as you feel comfortable doing it. The first theorem is much stronger than you need. It would be worth repeating Lee's argument for your problem to make sure, since the two are homeomorphic, his argument should be the same for your original question.